# Python JIRA jira.issue slow performance

Tags: python, api, jira

I am trying to retrieve from JIRA tree graph of parent child issues
epic->story->task using python3.10  jira=3.1.1

for project with 400 issues it takes minutes to retrieve the result.

is there a way how to improve this code for better performance

The result is displayed in flask frontend web and response time 2minutes is not pleasant for users

```
jira = JIRA(options={'server': self.url, 'verify': False}, basic_auth=(self.username, self.password))

for singleIssue in jira.search_issues(jql_str=querystring, maxResults=False):
            issue = jira.issue(singleIssue.key)
            links = issue.fields.issuelinks
            
            for link in links:
                if hasattr(link, 'inwardIssue'):
                    item['inward_issue'] = link.inwardIssue.key
                if hasattr(link, 'outwardIssue'):
                    item['outward_issue'] = link.outwardIssue.key
                item['typename'] = link.type.nam
```

Comment: jira is famous for its slowness

Comment: yes, but question is wherether there is an api call to retrieve all link + link_type in single api call or whether I have to iterate and call every single jira task independently

Answer (score 0):

I realised this is moreless matter of flask and long queries handling.
It should be solved either by asynchronous calls or queuing.

Answer (score 0):

Limit the fields you are requesting via the "`fields=[ 'key' ]`" parameter to include only those which you need.

In your example you are fetching the whole issue twice: once from the `.search_issues()` iterator every time round the loop (as expected), and (unnecessarily) again in the `.issue()` call on the following line.